# Is it okay to set JavaScript variable values using inline PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dynamic

Suppose I have a php document and I want to know if the request was made with or without query parameters. To do this directly in JavaScript, i have to do some kind of hack because there is no in-built function to extract values from document's url. Although I don't mind doing the pure JS hack, I am curious to know if it is alright to embed some PHP inside JavaScript, convert some "php value" to "JS value" and use the JS value to proceed in my JavaScript code. In case if value should be rendered in the web page, set it using jQuery's `.text` method to ensure XSS protection.

Something like this:

```
<?php
    $name = $_GET['name'];
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let name = "<?php echo $name?>";
        if (name === 'Devashish') {
            console.log("Hello me!")
            // do Devashish things
        } else {
            console.log("Please die");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that's fine. The alternatives would be to place the PHP value in an attribute on an element and read it from the DOM in JS, or to use AJAX.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, though you should probably json_encode it. `<?=json_encode($name);?>`

Answer (score 0):

There are too many thoughts on this.

To add some security you can do as follows:

If you are using latest javascript like ES6 or higher, use `const name = 'xyz'` or using javascript [freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) or `seal`. That will prevent modification to variables.